# Assigning missing edge cost to an MCST

Tags: graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I've come across this question while solving an old exam paper. I hardly have an idea how to tackle this problem based on the options given.

Consider the following undirected graph **G** with some edge cost missing. 
[image: MCST]

Suppose the dashed edges form a *Minimum Cost Spanning Tree (MCST)* from **G**. then which of the following inequalities **NEED NOT** hold ?

1. cost(a,b) ≥ 6
2. cost(b,e) ≥ 5
3. cost(e, f) ≥ 5
4. cost(a,d) ≥ 4
5. cost(b,c) ≥ 4

Answer (score 0):

The addition of any edge to the tree will create a loop. If the edge is not the of highest weight in that loop then removing the edge which is of highest weight and adding the given edge back will create a spanning tree with lower weight. So the fact that the tree is given as minimum weight implies that the weight of each remaining edge is greater than or equal to the weights of the edges in the loop formed when the given edge is added. For example, adding ab creates the loop abde. So cost(ab) must be greater than or equal to 5, otherwise the tree formed by adding ab and removing de will be a lower weight spanning tree than the given tree. Applying this to all edges not in the tree gives

- cost(ab)≥5
- cost(ad)≥5
- cost(bc)≥4
- cost(be)≥5
- cost(ef)≥5

Two of the choices given don't match these, but one of them holds *a fortiori* leaving one possible correct answer.

Comment: Didn't get the last point clearly? Out of edges AB and AD which one need not have a lower bound and why?

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. The question is which option is not necessarily true, that would happen if the lower bound was too high.